# Change the IP address of my LoadBalancer on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I want to change the IP address of my LoadBalancer ingress-nginx-controller in Google Cloud. I have now assigned the IP address via LoadBalancer. See the screenshot. Unfortunately it is not adopted in GKE. Why? Is that a bug?
[GKE lb IP address change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdOPR.png)

Comment: Did you reserved IPaddress in Google Cloud and include it in Ingress? What is you configuration? Could you share some environment information? What gke version, how did you deploy nginx, how did you reserve Global IP address in GCP?

Comment: Yes, I have reserved an IP address via the VPN network menu item. The IP is not assigned anywhere. I created my ingress-nginx-controller with kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Answer (score 3):

I have verified this on my `GKE` test cluster.

When you [Reserving a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) it isn't assigned to any of your VMs. Depends on how you `created cluster`/`reserved ip` (standard or premium) you can get error like below:

```
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: failed to create forwarding rule for load balancer (a574130f333b143a2a62281ef47c8dbb(default/nginx-ingress-controller)): googleapi: Error 400: PREMIUM network tier (the project's default network tier) is not supported: The network tier of specified IP address is STANDARD, that of Forwarding Rule must be the same., badRequest
```

In this scenario I've used cluster based in `us-central-1c` and `reserved IP` as `Network Service Tier: Premium`, `Type: Regional` and used region where my cluster is based - `us-central-1.` My `ExternalIP: 34.66.79.1X8`

**NOTE** `Reserved IP must be in the same reagion as your cluster`

**Option 1:** - Use [Helm chart](https://helm.sh/)

Deploy Nginx

```
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress  --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=34.66.79.1X8,rbac.create=true
```

Service output:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.8.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                      5h49m
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.8.5.158    <pending>     80:31898/TCP,443:30554/TCP   27s
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.8.13.209   <none>        80/TCP                       27s
```

Service describe output:

```
$ kubectl describe svc nginx-ingress-controller
...
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  32s   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   5s    service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

Final output:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.8.0.1      <none>         443/TCP                      5h49m
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.8.5.158    34.66.79.1X8   80:31898/TCP,443:30554/TCP   35s
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.8.13.209   <none>         80/TCP                       35s
```

**Option 2** - Editing [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke) YAMLs before deploying Nginx

As per docs:
Initialize your user as a cluster-admin with the following command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```

Download YAML

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Edit `LoadBalancer` service and add `loadBalancerIP: <your-reserved-ip>` like below:

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.13.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.35.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 34.66.79.1x8             #This line
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
```

Deploy it `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`. Service output below:

```
$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.8.0.1     <none>        443/TCP                      6h6m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.8.5.165   <pending>     80:31226/TCP,443:31161/TCP   17s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.8.9.216   <none>        443/TCP                      18s
                   6h6m
...
```

Describe output:

```
$ kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  40s   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   2s    service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

Service with reserved IP:

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.8.5.165   34.66.79.1X8   80:31226/TCP,443:31161/TCP   2m22s
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.8.9.216   <none>         443/TCP                      2m23s
```

**In Addition**

Also please keep in mind that you should add `annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` in your `ingress` resource when you want force `GKE` to use `Nginx Ingress` features, like [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

Answer (score 0):

The following method works well:

Prerequisites:

- Ingress Controller Installed
- Ingress Load Balancer Service created
- External Load Balancer created
- Ingress Resource created
- Static IP reserved

Imagine that the static IP needs to be assigned as the External Load Balancer IP.

1. Save locally and Delete the Ingress Load Balancer Service. This will delete the External Load Balancer too.
2. Save locally and delete the Ingress Load Balancer.
3. Recreate the Ingress Load Balancer Service with the following line. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  = your reserved static ip

   ```
    spec:
      loadBalancerIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   ```
4. Recreate the ingress resource