# Invalid value for nginx path

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My nginx ingress is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "gcloud-ip"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: client
          servicePort: 3333
      - path: /api/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: hasura-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

And i'm getting:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource': '{ "name": "k8s2-um-zhm30g1t-default-nginx-ymq8cimb", "hostRule": [{ "host": ["*"], "pathMatc...'. Invalid path pattern, invalid
```

Have looked at a lot of resources and this doesnt make sense, as the regexp is valid and annotations are correct i believe can anyone help?

Comment: Did you setup nginx ingress controller on your cluster? That error seems like GKE attempted to handle the ingress using its own ingress controller which does not support regexp.

Comment: Hey, yes ive got nginx running, and the annotation to register the ingress with nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing annotations from 2 Ingress Controlles. [GCP Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) and [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

Annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:` is `GCP Ingress` specific, and cannot be used with different `Ingress` controller like `Nginx Ingress`. You will not find this annotation in [Nginx Ingress Annotation List](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).

In the same `Ingress` object you are using `rewrite` annotation which is `Nginx Ingress` specific.

To sum up, you are getting this error as you are using 2 annotations from 2 different controllers. Similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253485/google-cloud-kubernetes-ingress-static-ip-address-not-reflected-and-different-fr).

To resolve your issue, you have to decide which `Ingress Controller` you will use. Please find both options below:

**GCP INGRESS**

If you would like to use `GCP Ingress` you have to use path without `rewrite` feature of `NGINX Ingress` controller.

Instead of:

```
paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
      ...
      - path: /api/?(.*)
```

Use:

```
paths:
      - path: /
      ...
      - path: /api/
```

Your services that are exposing your apps are required to be of `NodePort` type. Also you will need to **remove** both annotations:

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`
- `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

**NGINX INGRESS**

As annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` is Google Cloud specific, you cannot use it with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`.

If you have `Static IP` reserved in `GCP`, you should apply this IP as `loadBalancerIP` in `Nginx Ingress Controller`, not in `Ingress` resource.

I have already described how to deploy `Nginx Ingress Controller` with reserved static IP. You can find it by following below link:

- [Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Google Cloud Kubernetes Ingress static IP address not reflected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064321/11148139).

Please keep in mind that answer is several months old and repo has been changed since then. For up-to-date option you should use below commands. Please remember to change `<YourGlobalIP>` to your `ReservedIP`.

```
$ helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
$ helm repo update
$ helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=<YourGlobalIP>,rbac.create=true
```

Helm will deploy `Nginx Ingress Controller` with `ReservedIP`. Later you will need to remove `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` annotation and deploy `Ingress`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: first-service
          servicePort: 81
      - path: /api/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: second-service
          servicePort: 82
```

**Side Note**

Please remember that reserved address must be `Network Service Tier: Premium` and must have `Region` same as your cluster. The services that traffic from `nginx-ingress-controller` is sent from, should be either: `ClusterIP` or `NodePort`.

I have tested this scenario with 2 hello world applications v1, v2 and IP reserved was: `35.222.174.237` on `us-central1`

```
$ kubectl get ing
NAME      HOSTS   ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
ingress   *       35.222.174.2377   80      27s
$ curl 35.222.174.237/api/something
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: second-deployment-5b5bbb7f4-tzsd4
$ curl 35.222.174.237/test
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: first-deployment-85b75bf4f9-rtbn9
```